# Is Krichever's constuction "inverse" to finding the spectral curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, integrable-systems

There is Krichever's algebro-geometric construction of solutions to the KP equations starting from a curve X together with extra data.

There is a way to find the spectral curve given a point of the Sato Grassmannian parametrizing solutions of KP equations, which is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85693/from-sato-grassmannian-to-spectral-curve/85695)

Question: if I apply Krichever construction to a curve X with extra data, getting a point in the Sato Grassmannian, and then find the spectral curve of this point as above, will I get back the curve X?